# squar root of a negative operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

I know that the square root is defined for positive operators, i.e,A square root of a positive operator A is a self-adjoint operator B satisfying B^2 = A.
Is defined as the square root of negative operators?Is there √(-A)?(where A is an operator)

Answer (score 1):

Note that an operator $A$ is negative if and only if $A = -B$ for a positive operator $B$.

We can simply define $\sqrt{A} = i\sqrt{B}$, for example, and we would indeed have $(\sqrt{A})^2 = A$.  This operator will no-longer, however, generally be self-adjoint (in fact, $(\sqrt{A})^* = -\sqrt{A}$).

Note that a negative operator $A$ cannot have a self-adjoint square root.  For any self-adjoint operator $M$, $M^2 = M^*M$, which must be positive.

Comment: Can be written A=B+iC where B ,C are real matrix and A is complex matrix?

Comment: If $A$ is a complex matrix, we can always write $A = B + iC$ for real matrices $B$ and $C$.  I think that is what you're asking, but I don't see how it is relevant to your question.